# Single Featured Image Repeating

Tags: theme-development, post-thumbnails

I am attempting to create a listing of Blog Posts by Date(Month) and show the featured image for each.

```
                <div id="datePostTime"><h2>Posts for <?php echo get_the_date('F, Y'); ?></h2></div>
                <?php // The loop ?>
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            echo "<div id='post_thumbnail'>";
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                                echo '<h4>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</h4>';
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        the_post();
                        the_content();
                        echo "<br />";
                        echo "<div id='the_post_date'>";
                            the_date('','Article posted on ', '.');
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "<br />";
                    } // end while
                } // end if ?>
```

My code above is showing each individual blog post. However, the very first thumbnail image is then posted for each blog post. So regardless of what thumbnail I pick for the post, all of them show the same image as the first one loaded.

So it looks like this -

```
> Image 1
> My Post
> Post date
> Image 1 again
> My next post
> next post date
```

Why am I having repeating thumbnail images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {
                    while ( have_posts() ) {
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            echo "<div id='post_thumbnail'>";
                                the_post_thumbnail();
                                echo '<h4>' . get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt . '</h4>';
                            echo "</div>";
                        }
                        the_post();
```

You are calling your thumbnail before `the_post()`. Just move `the_post()` to before `if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {`

Comment: This fixed it. Thank you. Sometimes it just takes an extra pair of eyes.